# Programmatically set random number in images

Tags: android, random, textview, imageview

I have 4 speech bubble, which of 2 have question in white speech bubble and another 2 blue bubble have answers . I have done showing random image but how to generate question and answers randomly,i have confusion in that. I did not understand **how to programmatically set text in image**( speech bubble in this case). These are images cleaging more of my problem.!

[image]

next time question display following types.

[image]

i have done following code:

```
public class TestingActivity extends Activity  {

    ImageView i1, i2, i3, i4;
    int TwoArray[][] = new int[6][5];
    static int i;
    static int j;
    static int a = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setupVeiw();
        setImages();    
    }
   // Shuffle here   
    private void setupVeiw() {

        i1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        i2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);    
        i3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        i4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    }    
    public int getImage(int val)
    {
        if (val == 0)
            {
                 // How to set programmatically **questions** numbers in spechh bubble
             return R.drawable.speech_white;
        }    
        else 
            {
                 // How to set programmatically **answers** numbers in spechh bubble
             return R.drawable.speech_blue;
        }    
    }
    public void setImages()
    {
        try {

            int numArray[] = { 0, 0,1, 1 };    
            shuffleList(numArray);    
            for (i = 0; i < numArray.length - 1; i++) 
                    {
                switch (i) 
                            {
                    case 0:
                        i1.setImageResource(getImage(numArray[i]));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        i2.setImageResource(getImage(numArray[i]));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        i3.setImageResource(getImage(numArray[i]));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        i4.setImageResource(getImage(numArray[i]));
                        break;
                                default:
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am waiting for your good advice.
Thank you advance.

Answer (score 2):

Would be nice if you would use TextView instead, you can still set a background image in text view.

First, to generate a question, you can create a class named Question with the following properties.

```
public static int ADDITION = 1; // for example's sake

double x, y; // your variables
int operation; // operation

public Question(double x, double y, int operation) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.operation = operation
}

public double returnAnswer() {
  double answer = 0;
  if(operation == Question.ADDITION) {
    answer = x + y;
  }

  return answer;
}
```

And then you can generate questions

```
Question firstQuestion = new Question(Math.random(), Math.random(), Question.ADDITION);
```

Instead of using ImageViews to display the question, you can use TextViews. Use the `setText()` method to display the question and the `setBackground()` method to change the background image.

Comment: what do you mean?? tell me little more details.